# Classification of 2-dim topological manifold (not necessarily second countable)

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I quote from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Classification_of_closed_surfaces): "The classification theorem of closed surfaces states that any connected closed surface is homeomorphic to some member of one of these three families:

- the sphere;
- the connected sum of g tori, for $g\geq 1$;
- the connected sum of k real projective planes, for $k\geq 1$."

What if we drop the "second countable" requirement? E.g. using the long line $L$, we can construct surfaces like $L^2$ and $S^1\times L$, though these are not closed.

> How to classify all Hausdorff, connected, closed, 2-dimensional topological manifold?

Comment: What do you mean by "second conutable" in the title.

Comment: Every closed 2-dimensional manifold is second countable, so the classification is identical whether or not one troubles to mention second countability explicitly.

Comment: @ Lee: so you mean, hausdorff + compact + locally euclidean imply second countable?